# Any javascript libraries that convert "google compatible search phrases" into a SQL where clause?

Tags: library, javascript

I'm trying to find a javascript library that safely converts google compatible search phrases to a parameter based SQL where clause.

It doesnt have to be 100% google compatiable, but support ORs, phrases, ANDs and NOTs.

I mean phrases like this:

`test me out "hi there" ("you" OR NOT "me")`

I've found this:
https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder

Which avoids the "google search phrase" parsing by supplying a GUI to do this, but does generate a parameterized SQL query.

Is there any Google compatible search phrase parsers out there? Or something very similar?